# How to order by ascending and descending JSON with a condition in lodash or javascript

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to sort by ascending and descending order of the array of object below using javascript or lodash. The conditions are below:

1. This array will have objects with duplicate id
2. I want to sort the array based on 'name' and get the unique 'number' fields in an array based on the 'name' sort with a specific 'id'.

This is the data.

```
var data = [
  { id: 1, age: 36, name: 'ram', number: 11},
  { id: 2,  age: 40, name: 'sam', number: 11 },
  { id: 3, age: 37, name: 'roy', number: 11 },
  { id: 1, age: 41, name: 'fil', number: 12 },
  { id: 2,  age: 43, name: 'joy', number: 12 },
  { id: 3, age: 46, name: 'john', number: 12 }
]
```

Expected output when sorting based on name when id='1' and in ascending order:

```
[12,11]
```

Expected output when sorting based on name when id='2' and in descending order:

```
[11,12]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to split up your problem:

1. [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array on `id === x`;
2. [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the resulting array;
3. [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the resulting values so you only extract the `number`:

```js
var data = [
  { id: 1, age: 36, name: 'ram', number: 11},
  { id: 2,  age: 40, name: 'sam', number: 11 },
  { id: 3, age: 37, name: 'roy', number: 11 },
  { id: 1, age: 41, name: 'fil', number: 12 },
  { id: 2,  age: 43, name: 'joy', number: 12 },
  { id: 3, age: 46, name: 'john', number: 12 }
]

const id = 1;
const result = data
  .filter(row => row.id === id)
  .sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
  .map(row => row.number);
  
console.log(result);
```